# Back button angularjs issue

Tags: javascript, html, button, angularjs, back

I have this routing code for my app

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('',
                    {
                        controller:'competitionsController',
                        templateUrl:'competitions.html'
                    })
                .when ('/teams/',
                    {
                        controller:'teamsController',
                        templateUrl:'teams.html'
                    })
                .when('/squad/',
                    {
                        controller:'squadController',
                        templateUrl:'squad.html'
                    })
                .when('/player/',
                    {
                        controller:'playerController',
                        templateUrl:'player.html'
                    })
                .otherwise('');
        });
```

The order I display the information follows like that Competitions/Teams/squad/player

It works perfectly until I click in the navigator back button from squad or player pages, where it doesn't work well, it throws a "error loading pages" and it return to the competitions page. What I'm doing wrong?

You can check the behaviour of this here: http://balonmano100.p.ht/prueba/

Thanks

Comment: could you provide some info on the error

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. Origin http://balonmano100.p.ht is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

It changes the url in the browser removing the /prueba/ andd replacing it for /teams/, and it would be /prueba/teams. Fowards it does it right but backwards it fails

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your url via the *href* attribute in your link tag.  Try using `ng-click` and the `$location` object to set the browser's url.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="goTo('myUrlPart')">My Link</a>
</div>
```

Then in your controller

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$location',function($scope,$location){
        $scope.goTo = function(url){
            $location.path(url);
        }; // end goTo
    }]); // end myCtrl / myApp
```

Comment: I just noticed you're using jquery mobile, you may want to take a look at this explanation of using Angularjs with JQM and routing: http://simonguest.com/2013/04/08/jquery-mobile-and-angularjs-working-together/